# Google maps infobox.js load remote marker data

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map with multiple markers, each with an infobox, the same as this jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/ccj9p/7/

Around line 73 of the example:

```
//here the call to initMarkers() is made with the necessary data for each marker.  All markers are then returned as an array into the markers variable
    markers = initMarkers(map, [
        { latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(49.47216, -123.76307), address: "Address 1", state: "State 1" },
        { latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(49.47420, -123.75703), address: "Address 2", state: "State 2" },
        { latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(49.47530, -123.78040), address: "Address 3", state: "State 3" }
    ]);
```

the markers array is created. This works fine as is, but I need to create the markers array dynamically, by calling a PHP script. Can anyone tell whether this would be possible and if so, could you suggest how the PHP could be structured and echoed?

I know this is probably very stupid but here's what I have already tried:

PHP:
For now, simply echos

```
{ latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(52.931429, -1.448307), title: "Test Business", subtitle: "Design", website: "mywebsite.com" }
```

JS:

```
$.get("/listings/businesses", function(data) {
            var loaded_businesses = data;
            var businesses = new Array(loaded_businesses);    
            //here the call to initMarkers() is made with the necessary data for each marker.  All markers are then returned as an array into the markers variable
            markers = initMarkers(map, businesses);
        });
```

I don't get a js error, just no markers appear on the map.

I would be really very grateful for any suggestions as how I should be approaching this!

Comment: perhaps I should have added... please be gentle with me, this is my first stackoverflow post! Am not looking for completed code examples necessarily, just suggestions as to how to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it and here is the complete code in case it helps someone else.

Remember, I am using infobox.js to create the info boxes on the markers:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js

JS:

```
if($('#map_canvas').length > 0)
    {
        var cityCentre = new google.maps.LatLng(52.922298, -1.477275),
            markers,
            myMapOptions = {
                scrollwheel: false,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                zoom: 12,
                center: cityCentre,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myMapOptions);

        function initMarkers(map, markerData) {
            var newMarkers = [],
                marker;

            for(var i=0; i<markerData.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    draggable: false,
                    position: markerData[i].latLng,
                    visible: true,
                    icon: 'assets/images/pin.png'
                }),
                    boxText = document.createElement("div"),
                    //these are the options for all infoboxes
                    infoboxOptions = {
                        content: boxText,
                        disableAutoPan: false,
                        maxWidth: 0,
                        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0),
                        zIndex: null,
                        boxStyle: {
                            background: "none",
                            opacity: 1,
                            width: "320px"
                        },
                        closeBoxMargin: "12px 10px 2px 2px",
                        closeBoxURL: "/assets/images/map-infobox-close-placeholder.gif",
                        infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
                        isHidden: false,
                        pane: "floatPane",
                        enableEventPropagation: false
                    };

                newMarkers.push(marker);
                //define the text and style for all infoboxes
                //boxText.style.cssText = "margin-top: 8px; background:#fff; color:#3a3c17; font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-size:1.4em; padding: 14px; border-radius:10px; -webkit-border-radius:10px; -moz-border-radius:10px;";
                boxText.style.cssText = "color:#3a3c17;";
                boxText.innerHTML = "<div class='info-inner'><p class='title'>" + markerData[i].title + "</p><p class='subtitle'>" + markerData[i].subtitle + "</p>" + markerData[i].website + "</div>";
                //Define the infobox
                newMarkers[i].infobox = new InfoBox(infoboxOptions);
                //Open box when page is loaded
                //newMarkers[i].infobox.open(map, marker); // hide markers on page load
                //Add event listen, so infobox for marker is opened when user clicks on it.  Notice the return inside the anonymous function - this creates
                //a closure, thereby saving the state of the loop variable i for the new marker.  If we did not return the value from the inner function,
                //the variable i in the anonymous function would always refer to the last i used, i.e., the last infobox. This pattern (or something that
                //serves the same purpose) is often needed when setting function callbacks inside a for-loop.
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        //newMarkers[i].infobox.close();
                        newMarkers[i].infobox.open(map, this);
                        map.panTo(markerData[i].latLng);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
            }

            return newMarkers;
        }

        var businesses = new Array();

        $.getJSON("/listings/businesses", function(json1) {
            $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
                var markerObject = {};
                markerObject.latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                markerObject.title = data.title;
                markerObject.subtitle = data.title;
                markerObject.website = data.website;
                businesses.push(markerObject);

            });
            markers = initMarkers(map, businesses);
        });
    }
```

and my PHP script simply echos out this JSON:

```
[{"title":"Marker 1","lat":"52.931429","lng":"-1.448307","address":"My Address from PHP","website":"www.flemming.co.uk"},{"title":"Marker 2","lat":"52.933706","lng":"-1.479549","address":"My Address 2 from PHP","website":"www.flemming2.co.uk"}]
```

No doubt the JavaScript could be improved, please feel free to suggest improvements! The actual piece of code that solved my problem is this:

```
$.getJSON("/listings/businesses", function(json1) {
            $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
                var markerObject = {};
                markerObject.latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                markerObject.title = data.title;
                markerObject.subtitle = data.title;
                markerObject.website = data.website;
                businesses.push(markerObject);

            });
            markers = initMarkers(map, businesses);
        });
```

I just needed to create an array of objects which then get passed to initMarkers()